# How do I unsubscribe correctly from angular service results?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a method in the component that calls a service which returns an observable

Component Method code

```
 public upload(file) { 
    this.Service.ToBase64(files[0])
        .subscribe(data => (this.convertedFile = data));
    }
```

This works fine but when I chain unsubscribe to it, it stops working.

With Unsubscribe - This does not work

```
 public upload(file) { 
    this.Service.ToBase64(files[0])
        .subscribe(data => (this.convertedFile = data)).Unsubscribe();
    }
```

Service Code method

```
 convertedFile$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

ToBase64(file: any) {
    const myReader = new FileReader();
    myReader.onloadend = e => {     
      this.convertedFile$.next(myReader.result.toString().split(',')[1]);
    };
    myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    return this.convertedFile$.asObservable();
  }
```

As this a subject, I would like to unsubscribe. How can I do that correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is `unsubscribe()` not `Unsubscribe()`. But a more elegant way to get a value of observable and destroy the subscription is use the first operator like that:

```
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';


  public upload(file) { 
    this.Service.ToBase64(files[0]).pipe(first())
        .subscribe(data => (this.convertedFile = data));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare a Subscription property

First in your component

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
```

Then

```
fileSubscription: Subscription;
```

And in your method

```
 public upload(file) { 
    this.fileSubscription = this.Service.ToBase64(files[0])
       .subscribe(data => (this.convertedFile = data));
    }
```

In ngOnDestroy method

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.fileSubscription) {
        this.fileSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: I am new to Angular, Is this the best way to handle unsubscription? Also, is it the best way to get results from service using subject? Can I do something easier or better?

Comment: There are other ways to unsubscribe but for me this is the most understandable way to do it. Currently I'm not using ngOnDestroy method to unsubscribe I'm using a **decorator** but this need more knowledge about Angular framework.